# How to sort an array?

Tags: iphone, ios

> I am geting stuck here
>   I have array of latitude and longitude here , Get it from JSON Parsing

```
Arr_Lat=[[[[main valueForKey:@"responseData"]valueForKey:@"results"]valueForKey:@"lat"] copy];
Arr_Long=[[[[main valueForKey:@"responseData"]valueForKey:@"results"]valueForKey:@"lng"] copy];
```

I had calculate the distance between Current Location And array of lat and long index wise and store in to a Array......

```
CLLocation *currLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:appDel.curr_lat longitude:appDel.curr_long];

CLLocation *destLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:appDel.str_lat longitude:appDel.str_long];

distance = [destLoc distanceFromLocation:currLoc]/1000;

DistStr = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:@" %0.3f",distance];


    [appDel.Arr_distance addObject:DistStr];
```

I had sort the distance like this

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES]autorelease];


sortedFloats = [appDel.Arr_distance sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                             [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

I had display the title,address and distance but address and distance are not MATCH 
I want to sort address according to ascending distance array....

Thanks For Help in Advance.................

Comment: where is your address title stored ?

Comment: I get this from Jeson parsing                               Arr_address=[[[[main valueForKey:@"responseData"]valueForKey:@"results"]valueForKey:@"addressLines"] copy];                                                                       Arr_title = [[[[main valueForKey:@"responseData"] valueForKey:@"results"]valueForKey:@"titleNoFormatting"] copy];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arr_distance is NSString and I think it's not correct to sort an array like that.
Try this:

```
sortedFloats = [appDel.Arr_distance sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSString *dis1, NSString *dis2){
    if ([dis1 floatValue] < [dis2 floatValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
}];]
```

You may need to exchange the NSOrderedDescending or NSOrderedAscending as you need.